# The SMS program keeps sending the same content to the same phone number

Tags: android, service, sms, alarm

I'm having to do a schedule SMS program, everything works OK, except the only one: in the second time i try to send SMS, the program send the same content as in the first one, to the same phone number as in the first time.
Here's my code:

main_activity, sendBtn:

```
sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try { 
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(main_activity.this, MyAlarmService.class);

                String smsNumber = phoneNo.getText().toString();
                String smsText = edit.getText().toString();

                if (smsNumber.length() != 0 && smsText.length() != 0){


                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putCharSequence("extraSmsNumber", smsNumber);
                    bundle.putCharSequence("extraSmsText", smsText);
                    myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
                    String text = mTimeDisplay.getText().toString() + " " + mDateDisplay.getText().toString();


                    DateFormat formatter ; 
                    Date date ; 
                    formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd/MM/yyyy");
                    date = (Date)formatter.parse(text);


                    Calendar setCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    setCalendar.setTime(date);


                    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(main_activity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);

                    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();                

                    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, setCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

                    Toast.makeText(main_activity.this,
                            "Start Alarm with \n" +
                            "smsNumber = " + smsNumber + "\n" +
                            "smsText = " + smsText + "\n Contain : " + text,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else {
                    showDialog(ALERT_DIALOG_ID);
                }
            }
            catch (ParseException e)
            {Toast.makeText(main_activity.this,"Error!!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    }
        }
    }
    );
```

MyAlarmService:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyAlarmService extends Service {

String smsNumberToSend, smsTextToSend;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onBind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onDestroy()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart(intent, startId);

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    smsNumberToSend = (String) bundle.getCharSequence("extraSmsNumber");
    smsTextToSend = (String) bundle.getCharSequence("extraSmsText");

    sendSMS(smsNumberToSend, smsTextToSend);
}

private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)
{   
    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, null, null);    

}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyAlarmService.onUnbind()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}
```

}

I really need help, plz help me find a solution as fast as possible, thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(main_activity.this, 0, myIntent, 0);
```

First you need to add a flag so the created PendingIntent wont be reused every time.

Then you need to add some unique request code, if not the previous PendingIntent will be canceled and replaced. I.e., if you would schedule two text messages to be sent only the last one would be sent.

```
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(main_activity.this, SOMETHING_UNIQUE, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me
I tried to vote Up for you, but it said I need 15 reputations to do that xD